# Does there exist such an interval?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

> > If $f: \mathbb{[a,b]} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is twice differentiable at a point $c$.
> >     Does there exist an interval $[p,q]$ in $[a,b]$ where $f$ is differentiable

I think here, $f'$ is continuous at $c$.Then by the definition of continuity there must exist such an interval

Comment: How do you **define** "twice differentiable at $c$" if $f$ is not differentiable on a neighborhood of $c$?

Comment: @ClementC. and Epsilon Delta [I seriously don't get how twice differentiable at a point implies differentiable in an interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4275826/why-twice-differentiable-at-a-point-implies-differentiable-in-an-interval) please help here

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes, but not for the reason you've provided. Continuity is not as strong of a claim as differentiability is, as the latter implies the former but not the other way around.

However, since $f$ is twice differentiable at $c$, that means that its derivative at point $c$ is differentiable.

Now assume that there are no intervals around $c$ that are differentiable. Then, the derivative of $f$ could not be shown to be differentiable, since $f'$ wouldn't even be continuous at $c$. Hence, the statement has been shown.

Comment: Which is so obvious now that you've said it,  that I dk why I didn't think of it.

Comment: Basically, the answer is "yes, by definition of twice differentiable."

Comment: @ClementC. Yea essentially lol

Comment: Don Thousand and @DanielWainfleet [I seriously don't get how twice differentiable at a point implies differentiable in an interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4275826/why-twice-differentiable-at-a-point-implies-differentiable-in-an-interval) please help here

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon . The usual definition of the existence of $g'(x)$ requires that $g(y$) exists for every $y$ in an interval  $J$ of non-zero length with $x\in J. $ In particular if $g'(x)=f''(x)=(f'(x))'.$